# Set default pdf viewer in BibDesk

Tags: pdf, bibdesk

Is it yet possible to set the default PDF viewer in BibDesk? And if so how? I can't find anything within recent years about this, was heavily discussed about 5+ years ago.

I know that I can open each file individually and ctrl click to select the program to open with, but would like to be able to open multiple files at the same time and avoid selecting from menus if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in BibDesk's "Fields" preference pane. There's a "PDF Viewer" popup button that (regrettably) should do what you want.

[image: prefpane screenshot]